# Ajax Search HTTPS issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress, ssl

I have the plugin installed on my staging site without https and it works fine. My live site is an exact copy of the staging server but I have an SSL on the live site. It works fine on staging but doesn't work on the live site so I am thinking it's SSL related.

The plugin is Ajax Search Pro for Wordpress. I contacted the author but his solution of clearing cache and deactivate reactivate doesn't work.

Here is an explainer video I made - [Watch here](http://www.screencast.com/t/JrwuePCspUQa)

[LIVE SITE](https://harvill-ind.com/product-category/sanitary-equipment/sanitary-hoses/)

[STAGING](http://harvillind.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/sanitary-equipment/sanitary-hoses/)

Please advise.

Comment: Your AJAX target script reports a 500 Internal Server Error – so go check the server logs.

Comment: Ok, I pulled the server log and here is the error:
`code`
[Fri Jan 29 14:56:47.102634 2016] [:error] [pid 9425] [client 12.34.246.73:14750] PHP Warning: require_once(/nas/content/live/harvillind/wp-content/plugins/ajax-search-pro//includes/imagecache.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nas/content/live/harvillind/wp-content/plugins/ajax-search-pro/search.php on line 11

Here is the search.php screenshot:
http://screencast.com/t/neSTtTZNhPn

Comment: Also I checked the staging server log and no errors, which is what I expected since the ajax search is working on staging server.